# How to yank the current line and the line above it in Vim?

Tags: vim, yank

What I need is to yank the current line and the line just above it.

For instance, in the following example:

```
3   My test line
4   Line above current line
5   My current line |(cursor)
6   Line below current line
```

How do I yank lines 5 and 4 when my cursor is located on line 5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> should do it, as in  *Yank in the direction of up one line*, since <kbd>y</kbd> will accept the next keystroke as a motion, and <kbd>k</kbd> alone represents motion up one line.

If you need your cursor to return to its original position, just add a <kbd>j</kbd> as <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>. You will probably see the cursor move inelegantly on screen, but it gets the job done.

Comment: But I want my cursor's final position to be placed at current line.

Comment: Silly me. Forgot than I can use `j` to move one line below.

Answer (score 6):

For this simple case, `yk` will do the trick. This is yank followed by a motion of *up one line*.

Generally, use `yNk`, e.g. `y3k` to yank the current line and the preceding 3 lines.

If you need to return to the cursor position after the yank, set a mark and return to the mark after the `yk`:

```
mmyk`m
```

If you need only remain on the same line where you began the yank, *not* the same cursor position, `ykj` is shorter.

Comment: If i want to go back to before last move, i tend to use <c-o>

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the Normal mode commands already mentioned in other answers,
one can use the `:yank` Ex command on a corresponding range of lines.  For
example, to copy the current line along with the line above it (without moving
the cursor) run

```
:-,y
```